# Page Tab App create and add to 'Page' (e.g. business page) : appid not found

Tags: redirect, fbml, facebook-iframe, facebook-page, facebook-apps

I'm having a similar problem to others in regards 'Page Tab' (i.e. We don't 'get it') and how to create one has changed so much I can't find the answer. I think it's because I am misunderstanding the intent of a 'Page Tab' and so am not configuring the fields correctly.

I thought doing this would be not too bad. All I want to do is have a flash app that scrolls through a Zazzle.com catalogue be available as an App (Page Tab) to add to a FB 'Page' (i.e. Business Page).

When I click on the app it should show in the 'news feed' middle section of FB the Zazzle.com flash catalogue app.

A search doesn't turn up the 'Page Tab' app I thought I made:

application.php?id=299076926798330

Basic info

App Display Name: Thunder Cell Catalogue

App Namespace: zazzlecat

Contact Email: info@example.com

App Domain:

Category: Other

Page Tab

Page Tab Name: Catalogue

Page Tab URL: http://www.zazzle.com/utl/getpanel?tl=Thunder%20Cell&zp=238461518639208139&rf=238461518639208139&st=date_created

Secure Page Tab URL: https://www.zazzle.com/utl/getpanel?tl=Thunder%20Cell&zp=238461518639208139&rf=238461518639208139&st=date_created

I save all this and go back to my personal FB page and use FB as 'Thunder Cell' 'Page' that I am admin of but I can find the app to add as a Page Tab.

But if I save 'Create a Community Page' for the app I can find the 'Community Page' for the app and when I go to it there I get 301ed to the Flash app running outside Facebook.

Do I need the embed those Zazzle Flash URLs in HTML?

The thing I really want to do is:

1. Have the Zazzle Flash Catalogue running at the top of the Facebook page in the middle area always without clicking on the Page Tab.
2. It would be nice if I could in the Facebook Develop create app process give a list of variables and values for this URL: getpanel?tl=Thunder%20Cell&zp=238461518639208139&rf=238461518639208139&st=date_created when I go to add this 'Page Tab' app to my 'Business Page' that would make it useful for other people.

Now I got this working easy enough with FBML (well a 'Page Tab' app anyway):

Note: I deleted the beginning part of several URLs because I couldn't post this question otherwise.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Ciao